# R Shiny DT navigate to the table's last page via an action button

Tags: r, shiny

I have a Shiny app that allows the user to enter their project details to the database. This is achieved by the `Add Project Details Button` that adds an empty row to the table. Now the next step is:

- When the add button is clicked, the app automatically goes to the
  last record/page (`that now has the new empty row`) instead of having the user to click on
  the last page number.

How can I do this?

Sample Data (`df`):

```
structure(list(Reference.Number = c("33333", "44444", "22222", 
"55555", "66666"), Request.Date = c("1/6/2022", "1/6/2022", "1/19/2022", 
"1/20/2021", "1/24/2022"), Requestor.Name = c("Comm Dist 3 by Kitty", 
"Comm Dist 3 by Kitty", "Updated maps for David", 
"    Stone Cold", "Updated SOE 60 inch wall map"), Requestor.Dept.Div = c("C 3 Staff", 
"C 3 Staff", "Unincorp & Comm", "Mt.Rushmore AME Church Ft. Billy", 
"SOE"), Requestor.Phone = c("", "", "", "", ""), Contact.Person = c("Tommy", 
"Tommy", "Bob", "Bob", "Joe"), Contact.Phone = c("1111", 
"2222", "3333", "ext 1111", "3434"), Deadline = c("1/20/2022", 
"1/20/2022", "1/22/2022", "", "1/24/2022"), Project.Description = c("45x36 portrait map ", 
"45x36 portrait map  ", 
"24x24 Unincorporated areas, "Percent Females Aged 25 - 55  Below Poverty Level By Zip Code", 
"SOE Wall Map 60x60 p), Project.File.Location = c("", 
"", "C:\\ABC\\Tommy\\work|Map-Projects\\BD Unincororated\\#14785 Unincorporated 24x24.pdf", 
"C:\\ABC\\Demographics\\Demographic_Request\\FemalesAge10-18BelowPoveryLevel\\FemalesAge10-18BelowPoveryLevel.aprx", 
"C:\\ABC\\Tommy\\work|Map-Projects\\BD Unincororated\\#14786 V P 60x60.pdf"
), PDF.File.....Map.Name.... = c("", "", "", "C:\\ABC\\Demographics\\Demographic_Request\\FemalesAge10-18BelowPoveryLevel\\pdfs\\MapNo14785.pdf", 
""), Assigned.To = c("", "", "", "", ""), Completion.Date = c("", 
"", "", "", ""), Notes = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Year = c(2022, 
2022, 2022, 2022, 2022)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Code:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)
library(DT)
library(tidyverse)

    # Define UI for application that draws a histogram
    ui =   navbarPage(
                      tags$style("table, .table {color: unset;} .dataTable th, .datatables input {color: white}"),
                      title = div("GIS Team Projects"),
                      theme = shinytheme("cyborg"),
                      tabPanel("GIS Projects",
                               icon = icon("info"),
                               div(p(h1("Instructions:"),style="text-align: justify;")),
                               p("1. The user can add their project details.", style="color:black"),
                               uiOutput("all"),
                      sidebarLayout(
                        sidebarPanel(
                          actionButton("addData", "Add Project Details"),
                          ),
                        mainPanel(
                          downloadButton("download1","Download data as csv"),                
                          DTOutput("contents")),)
                        )
    )
    
    # Define server logic required to draw a histogram
    server <- function(input, output) {
    
      myData = df
      
      # Create an 'empty' tibble 
       user_table =
         myData %>% 
          slice(1) %>% 
        # Transpose the first row of test into two columns
        gather(key = "column_name", value = "value") %>%
        # Replace all values with ""
        mutate(value = "") %>%
        # Reshape the data from long to wide
        spread(column_name, value) %>%
        # Rearrange the column order to match that of test
        select(colnames(myData))
       
       # Display data as is
       output$contents =
         renderDT(myData,
                  server = FALSE,
                  editable = TRUE,
                  options = list(lengthChange = TRUE),
                  rownames = FALSE)
       
       # Store a proxy of contents 
       proxy = dataTableProxy(outputId = "contents")
       
       # Each time addData is pressed, add user_table to proxy
       observeEvent(eventExpr = input$addData, {
         proxy %>% 
           addRow(user_table)
       })
      
    }
    
    # Run the application 
    shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

**UPDATE** Based on the answer, the app still does not go the last page after clicking the `Add Project Details` button.

Updated code:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)
library(DT)
library(tidyverse)

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui =    navbarPage(
                  tags$style("table, .table {color: unset;} .dataTable th, .datatables input {color: white}"),
                  title = div("GIS Team Projects"),
                  theme = shinytheme("cyborg"),
                  tabPanel("GIS Projects",
                           icon = icon("info"),
                           div(p(h1("Instructions:"),style="text-align: justify;")),
                           p("1. The user can add their project details.", style="color:black"),
                           uiOutput("all"),
                  sidebarLayout(
                    sidebarPanel(
                      actionButton("addData", "Add Project Details"),
                      ),
                    mainPanel(
                      downloadButton("download1","Download data as csv"),                
                      DTOutput("contents"),
                      ## include JS code via tags$script(HTML(...)):
                      tags$script(HTML("
           Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler('messageJumpToLast', function(message) {
               // select the target table via its container ID and class:
               var target = $('#contents .dataTable');
               // display last page:
               target.dataTable().api().page('last').draw(false);
           });
           "))),
                    )
                    )
)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output, session) {

  myData = df
  
  # Create an 'empty' tibble 
   user_table =
     myData %>% 
      slice(1) %>% 
    # Transpose the first row of test into two columns
    gather(key = "column_name", value = "value") %>%
    # Replace all values with ""
    mutate(value = "") %>%
    # Reshape the data from long to wide
    spread(column_name, value) %>%
    # Rearrange the column order to match that of test
    select(colnames(myData))
   
   # Display data as is
   output$contents =
     renderDT(myData,
              server = FALSE,
              editable = TRUE,
              options = list(lengthChange = TRUE),
              rownames = FALSE)
   
   # Store a proxy of contents 
   proxy = dataTableProxy(outputId = "contents")
   
   # Each time addData is pressed, add user_table to proxy
   observeEvent(eventExpr = input$addData, {
     proxy %>% 
       addRow(user_table)
     session$sendCustomMessage('messageJumpToLast', 'some payload here, if needed')
   })
  
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the client listen to custom messages and execute Javascript functions you've prepared in the UI part (see section *from R to Javascript* [here](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/communicating-with-js.html)).

This might look like:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton('jumpToLast', 'jump to last page'),
  dataTableOutput('tableContainer'),
  ## include JS code via tags$script(HTML(...)):
  tags$script(HTML("
           Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler('messageJumpToLast', function(message) {
               // select the target table via its container ID and class:
               var target = $('#tableContainer .dataTable');
               // display last page:
               target.dataTable().api().page('last').draw(false);
           });
           ")
           )
)

server <- function(input, output, session){
  output$tableContainer <- renderDataTable(iris)

  ## when action button is clicked, send custom message to client:
  observeEvent(input$jumpToLast, {
    session$sendCustomMessage('messageJumpToLast', 'some payload here, if needed')
  })

}

shiny::shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thank you, so the app cannot be told to automatically go to the last page when the `Add Project Details` button is clicked unless the `jump to last` button has been added  to the code to do so?

Comment: That's a generalised example. In your specific case, you add the code to send a custom message to what you've already specified in your observer of input$addData (`observeEvent(input$addData, {...})`). Certainly you don't need an extra actionButton plus observer.

Comment: Good day, it's still not working,  please see updated question.

Comment: Your DTOutput has the ID "contents" (`DTOutput("contents")`). The script targets  "tableContainer" (`$("#tableContainer ...`)). You need to match both IDs.

Comment: Yes, I changed `var target = $('#tableContainer  .dataTable')` to  `var target = $('#contents .dataTable')` , but it still doesn't work, do I need to change/add something else too?

Comment: You need to enable immediate rendering of the datatable output like so: `dataTableProxy(..., deferUntilFlush = FALSE)`. That out of the way, please note that when adding code to a functioning example those additions would be the first place to go looking for what broke the working example. As opposed to hiring someone to hack your app in the first place ;-)